# How to not allow certain characters in "street address" in users account?

Tags: magento-1.9

There's a problem where people will enter their e-mail address in the "street address" field, so I want to add validation/error message to the fields:
 
[image]

Comment: if they add email address tell please enter street address am i correct?

Comment: Yes, basically if it would contain "@", it should display an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like that it will work. it is already defined in `js/prototype/validation.js`

So you can call focus on the input fields and their “class” attributes you will see some of them named: `“required-entry validate-street”`.  add `validate-street`

I checked in my local it will work :)

```
['validate-street', 'Please use only letters (a-z or A-Z) or numbers (0-9) or spaces and # only in this field.', function(v) {
                    return Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v) ||  /^[ \w]{3,}([A-Za-z]\.)?([ \w]*\#\d+)?(\r\n| )[ \w]{3,}/.test(v)
                }]
```

---

```
  <input 
                            type="text" 
                            name="street[]" 
                            value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getStreet(0)) ?>" 
                            title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" 
                            id="street_1"
                            maxlength="35" 
                            class="form-control required-entry" 
                            placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('Street') ?>*"
                        >
```

Add `form-control required-entry validate-street` in your class
Hope it will helpful.

Comment: Thanks! But where do I find the class of these input fields?

Comment: enable template path hint and check where it is. 
I will provide all place wait a min.

Comment: Street address files in themes

    template/customer/form/register.phtml

Shipping and billing are in your onepage checkout or onestep checkout
shipping.phtml
billing.phtml

Comment: app/design/frontend/{your theme} /default/template/customer/form/register.phtml

Comment: Could it be that for me it is: `app/design/frontend/{your theme} /default/template/customer/form/edit.phtml`?

Comment: yes update also that file :)

Comment: Follow up question: Do I still need to edit the `app/design/frontend/{your theme} /default/template/customer/form/register.phtml` if editing `app/design/frontend/{your theme} /default/template/customer/form/edit.phtml` works for me?

Comment: yes, street address are register,billing,shipping and edit.phtml in my account page. we need to do all pages